# How do I solve this integral using complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I'm having a hard time working on this practice problem. It says:

> Compute the integral:
>   $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{y^4+1}\,\mathrm{d}y$$

Comment: does the integral even include $dx$?

Comment: @PhaniRaj No, it's just as it's written.

Comment: @Tom: So it has $x$ as a parameter?

Comment: @Tom which would imply you can take x^2-3 out? -> $$(x^2-3) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y^4+4}dy$$

Comment: @Bob What would be the next step be to integrate this?

Comment: First, find the residues of that integrand.

Comment: @GEdgar Hmmm. Still having a hard time with this one.  I am trying to find the Laurent expansion, but not being successful.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-of-integral). In particular, proves you integral is $$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{8}}$$

Comment: To find the residues, you need not do Laurent expansions.  But you do need to factor the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be shed away by $y$ being the integration variable; you may call it $x$ as well. So we are told to compute
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^a{dx\over x^4+1}\ .$$
Embed the $x$-axis into the complex plane and consider there the region
$$\Omega:=\{z=x+iy\ |\ x^2+y^2< a^2,\ y>0\}\ .$$
Its boundary $\partial\Omega$ consists of the segment $[-a,a]$ on the real axis and a half circle of radius $a$. Apply to this situation the residue theorem
$$\int_{\partial\Omega}{dz\over z^4+1}=2\pi i\sum_{\zeta\in\Omega} {\rm Res}\biggl(z\mapsto {1\over z^4+1}\biggm| \zeta\biggr)$$
and finally let $a\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y^4+1}dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y^4+ 2y^2 +1 - 2y^2}dy=$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(y^4+ 2y^2 +1) - 2y^2}dy =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(y^2 +1)^2 - 2y^2} dy$$

Can you proceed?

You should find $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$